# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to practice reading text from a file in python 3.5, but I keep getting an error message.

Here's my code:

```
# A program that reads a text file and prints its contents on the screen
# so that each row contains a line number
# A reminder for UTF-8 users:


def insert_line_number(line, line_number):
    """
    A function that takes a line and a corresponding line number and joins them
    together.

    :param line: A line of text
    :param line_number: A corresponding line number
    :return: A line with teh line number at the beginning
    """
    line_with_number = "{:3d} {:s}".format(line_number, line)
    return line_with_number


def print_lines(file):
    """
    A function that reads lines from a file and prints them with an added line
    number.

    :param file: The file whose lines are to be printed
    :return: -
    """
    line_number = 0
    try:
        # Going through the lines, adding line numbers and printing the
        # resulting line
        for line in file:
            # Removing unnecessary characters from the end of the line
            line = line.rstrip()
            line_number += 1
            # Creating a line with the appropriate line number
            line_with_number = insert_line_number(line, line_number)
            print(line_with_number)
    except IOError:
        print("Error reading the file. Program will close.")


# Our main
def main():
    filename = input("Syötä tiedoston nimi: ")
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        print_lines(file)
        file.close()
    except IOError:
        print("Error opening the file. Program will close.")


# Program start
main()
```

...and here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/.../5.7.1(tiedostojen_lukeminen).py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:/.../5.7.1(tiedostojen_lukeminen).py", line 48, in main
    print_lines(file)
  File "F:/.../5.7.1(tiedostojen_lukeminen).py", line 32, in print_lines
    for line in file:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thomas K had this to say in another thread:

> "To put the same thing another way: when you open a file for reading,
>   the encoding parameter needs to be the encoding the file is already
>   in, not the encoding you want (you select that when you write the
>   file)."
>    – Thomas K Nov 20 '12 at 13:02

Before posting this here I was specifically instructed to use the encoding="utf-8" -parameter inside the open()-function. Without the parameter the code runs just fine on my machine, but if I include it, I get the error above.

I'd be interested to know what is going on behind the scenes. Why doesn't my code work when the parameter is included?

Comment: That is not utf-8 encoded, try `latin-1`

Comment: "latin-1" actually worked, as well as not having the parameter at all. Weird.

Comment: What does `sys.getdefaultencoding()` output?

Comment: If I had to guess, that would be the default encoding for the operating system I'm on, which is Windows 10.

Comment: That is what `import sys;sys.getdefaultencoding()` should output

Comment: So if I leave the parameter out, `open()` will use `sys.getdefaultencoding()` as the default value for the parameter?

Comment: In Python 3 per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) the default encoding for `open` is `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, which is `cp1252` on US Windows.  `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is `utf-8` on Python 3 and `ascii` on Python 2 (unless [explicitly changed](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/)).

Comment: Alright. Thank you.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I faced the same problem after using the latin-1 it worked fine. But previously my program worked for last 15-20 runs no complaint, but today it complains about the same error. Could you help me here to understand what's wrong. I am on Windows 10 OS.